# Raise error if BCP command fails to dump data into a file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, bcp

Using the BCP command I am generating files of SQL Server DB tables. The BCP command creates an empty file for each table when it's unable to dump data into the files. This can be caused by an error in query written or an empty variable is passed to the BCP command.

Is there any way we can capture these events as errors and make it return some error code?

I am performing this from a stored procedure. Is there any way I can handle this in SP?

Comment: Can you please update your question to include exactly how you are calling BCP in the Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 8):

Powershell is your friend here. When working with cmd commands in Powershell you can use the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable to read the result of the command you executed.

The code below passes a `BCP` command into the Invoke-Expression cmdlet and captures it's output.

```
$OutputPath = "C:\temp\Numbers-20151230.dat"

try
{
    $Command = "bcp dbo.Numbers out $OutputPath -T -n -S Localhost\JamesA_Test -d UtilityDB"
    $Output = Invoke-Expression -command $Command

    if ($LASTEXITCODE)
    { 
        throw $Output
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "BCP command failed: $Output"   
}
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle the error so I just used `Write-Host` to display the error for this example. You could log the error to the event log, a file, a table in SQL, etc.

Comment: Thank you James but I am performing this from a stored procedure. Is there any way I can handle this in SP?

Comment: You could use the Powershell code to create a SQL Agent Job that you call from your SP. This link is also an option but I wouldn't recommend doing this in production. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2087/how-to-execute-a-dos-command-when-xpcmdshell-is-disabled-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit vague with regards to *how* BCP is being executed, outside of it being done within a Stored Procedure. But since that is all we really know at the moment, I will assume that you are calling `BCP.EXE` from `xp_cmdshell`.

If you want to simply capture actual errors being thrown by `BCP`, then that is very easy to do since the `ERRORLEVEL` value is returned as an `INT` from the `xp_cmdshell` stored procedure:

```sql
DECLARE @ErrorLevel INT;
EXEC @ErrorLevel = xp_cmdshell
         N'BCP "SELECT * FROM sys.objects where 1=  " queryout C:\temp\BCPtest.txt -T -w ';
SELECT @ErrorLevel;
```

Returns:

```
1
```

If, however, you want to treat queries that complete successfully yet return 0 rows as an "error" condition, then that can also be done, it just requires a little more effort:

```sql
DECLARE @ErrorLevel INT;
EXEC @ErrorLevel = xp_cmdshell
   N'BCP "SELECT * FROM sys.objects where 1= 0 " queryout C:\temp\BCPtest.txt -T -w && (FORFILES /P C:\TEMP\ /M BCPtest.txt /C "CMD /C IF @fsize LSS 3 DEL C:\TEMP\BCPtest.txt" & IF NOT EXIST C:\temp\BCPtest.txt EXIT -3)';
SELECT @ErrorLevel;
```

Returns:

```
-3
```

Please note that the long command-line needs to be either kept as a single line, or placed into a `.CMD` script so that it works properly.

The additional logic, in a more readable format, is:

```
&& (
    FORFILES /P C:\TEMP\
             /M BCPtest.txt
             /C "CMD /C IF @fsize LSS 3 DEL C:\TEMP\BCPtest.txt"
    & IF NOT EXIST C:\temp\BCPtest.txt EXIT -3
   )
```

Explanation:

- `&&` this operator will run the command on the right side *only if* the command on the left side completed successfully. The reason for using this operator is to allow `BCP` to set the `ERRORLEVEL` value if it encounters an error; the commands on the right side are only needed if `BCP` does *not* run into an error yet returns 0 rows.
- `(` the parenthesis group the commands inside of them together. This allows us to run the `FORFILES` and `IF` commands only if `BCP` completes successfully. Otherwise, neither of the commands within the `(` and `)` are executed.
- `FORFILES` cycles through a list of files, specified by certain switches, and executes a command per each file that matches the criteria (similar to the `find` command in Unix).

  - `/P` is the starting path. It has to be a path and cannot contain the filename.
  - `/M` is the filename filter or "mask".
  - `/C` is the command to run for each file. It pretty much needs to start with `CMD /C`. The `IF` command tests the size of the file that is found via the `@fsize` variable that is substituted by `FORFILES` and if it is less than 3 (i.e. `LSS 3`) then it will just delete the file. In my testing I found that using either `-c` or nothing with `BCP` to indicate ASCII / VARCHAR output would result in an empty file of 0 bytes. But using the `-w` to indicate Unicode / NVARCAR output results in empty files of 2 bytes (which should be the Byte Order Mark). Hence testing for "size < 3" covers both scenarios.

    The reason for deleting the file is that it is something that can be tested for in the parent process. Because `CMD /C` is being used to run the command on files that are found by `FORFILES`, it is a sub-process and environment variables will not persist (similar to creating a local temporary table in Dynamic SQL) and exiting with an error code simply returns to the parent process like it was already going to. Creating an empty file as an indicator is an option, but then it either needs to be cleaned up or is clutter. And if the process is being considered an error for not returning any rows, then we don't want the file anyway.
- `&` this operator executes the command on the right side regardless of the success or failure status of the command on the left side.
- `IF` this does a simple test for the existence of the specified file and if that file does not exist, then it will run the specified command.

  - `EXIT -3` this exits the current process (which is the top-level OS process started by `xp_cmdshell`) while setting the `ERRORLEVEL` value to `-3`. You can change the `-3` to be any value you like, just be mindful to not use values already being used by `BCP` so that you are able to distinguish between them. The `EXIT` is only needed to be used explicitly if you want to set `ERRORLEVEL` (similar to either not specifying `RETURN` at the end of a stored procedure, or needing to specify it in order to pass back a non-`0` value).